# Size of cost raster in Least Cost Path plugin

Tags: raster, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

When I run the Least Cost Path plugin in QGIS, its success is dependant upon the dimensions of the 'cost raster'. If the original DEM or subsequent 'cost raster' it too large then the operation seems to fail.
With the successful example below, can anyone tell me what the "8765 * 7727" actually is/means?? It is not metres or kilometres. Is it pixels???

```
QGIS version: 3.8.3-Zanzibar
QGIS code revision: 685d8b15d2
Qt version: 5.11.2
GDAL version: 2.4.1
GEOS version: 3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 
PROJ version: Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Least Cost Path' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'BOOLEAN_OUTPUT_LINEAR_REFERENCE' : False, 'INPUT_COST_RASTER' : 'E:/BU Volunteer/QGIS/Ians-Rift-Valley/10-overlayed-maps/least-cost-stuff/adama.tif', 'INPUT_END_LAYER' : 'E:\\BU Volunteer\\QGIS\\Ians-Rift-Valley\\10-overlayed-maps\\least-cost-stuff\\adama.gpkg|layername=adama', 'INPUT_RASTER_BAND' : 1, 'INPUT_START_LAYER' : 'E:/BU Volunteer/QGIS/Ians-Rift-Valley/10-overlayed-maps/least-cost-stuff/awash-start-4326.gpkg|layername=awash-start-4326', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }

The size of cost raster is: 8765 * 7727
Searching least cost path...
Search completed! Saving path...
Execution completed in 4058.56 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'Output_least_cost_path_a74cf0f6_b4aa_4ee6_a876_ef6c26f4e164'}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Least Cost Path' finished
```

Comment: probably, pixels - but please continue with your existing question rather than spinning new ones off

Comment: I'm confused then. The rules of this platform suggested that this was another question - rather than complicating the original question.

Comment: this is all part of your ongoing problem with running least cost path

Comment: OK. Do I delete this question then?

Comment: it's fine the system will clean it up